# Form using admin-post.php gives 404 after submission

Tags: plugin-development, forms

I'm creating a custom form for a wordpress page, and I'm using admin-post.php as my action.
However, whenever I try to submit the form, I get a 404.

Below is the code which outputs the form:

```
function output_email_verification() {
      $error = '';
      if(isset($_COOKIE['rguroo_form_error'])) {
          $error = $_COOKIE['rguroo_form_error'];
          unset($_COOKIE['rguroo_form_error']);
      }
      return '<form action='.esc_url( admin_url("admin-post.php") ).'method="post">
                <p class="error">'.$error.'</p>
                <input type="radio" label="Purchase 12 months access" value="purchase" name="rguroo_desired_action" checked>Purchase 12 months access</input>
                <input type="radio" label="Renew account" name="rguroo_desired_action" value="renewal">Renew account</input>
                <input type="radio" label="Create trial account" name="rguroo_desired_action" value="trial">Create trial account</input>
                <p class="form-subtext">* indicates required field</p>
                <p>Email address*</p>
                <input type="text" name="rguroo_email" required>
                <p>Re-type email address*</p>
                <input type="text" name="rguroo_email_confirmation" required>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="rguroo_email_verification_form">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
            </form>';
}
```

This is the action that I've hooked onto admin-post.php

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_email_verification_form', 'verify_and_sanitize_email_form', $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 );
add_action( 'admin_post_email_verification_form', 'verify_and_sanitize_email_form', $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 );

// Email verification callback
function verify_and_sanitize_email_form() {
    if(empty($_POST) || !isset($_POST['rguroo_email']) || !isset($_POST['rguroo_email_confirmation']) || !isset($_POST['rguroo_desired_action'])) {
        send_form_error('There is one or more empty fields');
        return;
    }
    $sanitized_email = sanitize_email( esc_html($_POST['rguroo_email'] ));
    $sanitized_email_confirmation = sanitize_email( esc_html($_POST['rguroo_email_confirmation'] ));
    $desired_action = esc_html($_POST['rguroo_desired_action']);

    if(!is_email( $sanitized_email ) || !is_email( $sanitized_email_confirmation )) {
        send_form_error('Email is not valid');
        return;
    }

    if($sanitized_email !== $sanitized_email_confirmation) {
        send_form_error('Emails do not match');
        return;
    }

    if($desired_action !== 'purchase' || $desired_action !== 'renewal' || $desired_action !== 'trial') {
        send_form_error('Fatal error with radio buttons');
        return;
    }

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['rguroo_form_type'])) {
        send_form_error('Server error');
        return;
    }

    // student email verification logic
    $form_type = $_COOKIE['rguroo_form_type'];
    if($form_type === 'student') {
        $trail = substr($sanitized_email, -4);
        if($trail !== '.edu') {
            send_form_error('Not a valid student email');
            return;
        }
        // Other university specific logic here
    }
    setcookie('rguroo_form_action',$desired_action, 14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS);
    setcookie('rguroo_form_email', $sanitized_email, 14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS);

}

// Helper. Used to output an error
function send_form_error($msg) {
    setcookie('rguroo_form_error', $msg, 14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS);
}
```

Sorry about the mess of error validation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First of all...

Your `action` is called `rguroo_email_verification_form`, so you should use it when registering your hooks. But you use this instead:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_email_verification_form', 'verify_and_sanitize_email_form', $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 );
add_action( 'admin_post_email_verification_form', 'verify_and_sanitize_email_form', $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 );
```

It should be:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_rguroo_email_verification_form', 'verify_and_sanitize_email_form', $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 );
add_action( 'admin_post_rguroo_email_verification_form', 'verify_and_sanitize_email_form', $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 );
```

Also... These actions don't take any params, but you declare they should take one param (but later on, your function doesn't take any...)

Comment: The last parameter in add_action defaults to 1. Excluding the last two parameters of add_action would be completely identical to what I currently have. Also, I've fixed the mistake with the names, but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Krzysiek, there was an inconsistency between the action field in the form and the admin-post hook.

That being said, the real source the issue and the cause of the 404 was a formatting error.

```
<form action='.esc_url( admin_url("admin-post.php") ).'method="post">
```

Was outputting

```
<form action="https://rguroo.com/wp-admin/admin-post.phpmethod=post">
```

The correct tag was as follows:

```
<form action="'.esc_url( admin_url("admin-post.php") ).'" method="post">
```

I'm an idiot...